# Are Hindu scriptures limited to India?

Tags: scripture, india

I found that most of the Hindu scriptures and epics describe places in and around India.

Does any Hindu scripture mention about the Pyramids of Egypt or America or Africa?

Comment: no, there is no mention. The Hindu scriptures are older than the pyramids of Egypt or those in America.

Comment: Hindu Scriptures do mention other *dvipas* (continents). But pyramids might have not explicitly mentioned or we may be misinterpreting Pyramids as something.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Many Hindu scriptures mentioned about Muhammad (last messenger and prophet of Muslims) though they are much older than Muhammad; and many other future events.

Comment: Does it means Hindu religion and scriptures are limited to people in and around India ?

Comment: There is only one Hindu Scripture which mentions Prophet Muhammad, viz Bhavishya purana which is full of interpolations and the story of Muhammad is one of the interpolated parts of the scripture.

Comment: @Vikram any mention of Muhammad is a later interpolation. This was done by the Muslim invaders.

Answer (score 0):

The geography of events in all Hindu scriptures are confined only to the Indian sub-continent. If you look at the the various places where events of Hindu scriptures took place you get:

**Ramayana**:

- Northern most - the Himalayas eg. Hanuman brought sanjeevani leaves from the Himalayas
- Southern most - Lanka
- Eastern most - Pragjotishpur which is the ancient name of Assam is mentioned several times. There is a holy placed called Vasistha near Guwahati which is believed to the ashram of Ram's guru Vasistha
- Westernmost - Saraswati which is believed to be flow in modern day Pakistan to Allahabad where it met with the Gangan and Yamuna. Saraswati is mentioned six times in Valmiki Ramayana.

Beyond these four extreme locations, events of the Ramayana do not take place.

**Mahabharata**

Events of the Mahabharata have take place in a much wider geographical area

- Northernmost - Himalayas e.g. where Pandavs go on their journey to
  heaven
- Southern most - Lanka e.g. stories of Ram and Ravana were known in the Mahabharata era
- Eastern most - Manipur where Arjun's family Chitrangada and Babrubahana ruled. Pragjotishpur (Assam) is also mentioned e.g. Krishna and Satyabhama defeated Narakasur in Pragjotishpur. Ghatotkacha's mother Maurvi was the daughter of the senapati of Pragjyotishpur.
- Western most - Kaal Yavan the king of Yaman, king who attacked Mathura was from Yavan desh (Yaman) which was considered to be a kingdom from the west along with Gandhar. Ghandar is believed to be the modern day Kandahar in Afganistan where Shakunis father Subal ruled.

Outisde these 4 extreme boundaries in the North, South, East and West, there is ***no known reference to the involvement of the people any other lands or anything in those lands*** including pyramids of Egypt or America. It is natural to undestand that Mahabharata has a wider grography because it was written after the Ramayana.

It is also interesting to note from geographical point of view the rivers that were prominient during various yugs.

- During the Satya yug/Vedic ages, Saraswati was the most popular religious river and is mentioned much more than Ganga in the Rig Veda.
- In the Ramayana ages, Ram's ancestor Bhaghirath brought Ganga to earth to purify the souls of his ancestors. But the river Sarayu was already there on earth and so Sarayu it was much more popular in the Ramayana than the Ganga and several events of the Ramayana are connected to the river Sarayu
- In the Mahabharata, Ganga is clearly the most popular river

**Source**: All these information is not present collectively in one single scripture so the best reference would be the Rig Veda, Ramayana and the Mahabharata directly.

Comment: doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda - Outisde these 4 extreme boundaries in the North, South, East and West, there is no known reference to any other lands or anything in those lands including Egypt or South America.

Comment: Does it means Hindu religion and scriptures are limited to people in and around India ?

Comment: No Hindu religion is not limited only to the people in and around India. All it means it that, at the time of their writing, the Hindu scriptures mentioned about several places in and around India but nothing whatsoever is mentioned about distant lands like Iceland or Australia. However today, anybody in the world is welcomed even if they are outside the Indian subcontinent.

Comment: This is wrong. Sugriva talks in detail about various places around the earth while delegating vanaras to search the earth.  http://www.valmikiramayan.net/kishkindha/sarga40/kishkindha_40_frame.htm, http://www.valmikiramayan.net/kishkindha/sarga42/kishkindha_42_frame.htm, http://www.valmikiramayan.net/kishkindha/sarga43/kishkindha_43_frame.htm, etc.

Comment: @moonstar2001 - I get the point you are making However, the earth as a whole as been mentioned many times in out scriptures eg. King Prithu; after whom the earth was named as Prithvi; travelled over the entire earth and the Varaha avtar of Vishnu who save the entire earth from drowning. The entire earth always existed but in my answer, I have given the boundary of places where people of that place took part in story/events of the scriptures. Eg. Manipur in the east was an eventful place participating in the Mahabharat but lands to the east of Manipur such as China was not.

Comment: Other parts of the earth also have mention in religious texts. That is the point I am trying to make. Not merely that the earth existed.

Comment: @moonstar2001 - The way I am looking at it may be different form yours. The way you are looking at is the mention/existence of other places. This is trivial because the earth as a whole existed to other places will exist and will be mentioned. The way I am looking at it is - did the people of those other places participate in our scriptures. For example, the army of Yavan (believed to be modern Greece)  invaded Mathura under Kaal Yavan. But the people of modern Africa or Japan had nothing to do actively with the events of our scriptures.

Comment: 1. Gandhara where Gandhari/sakuni are from is modern day Kandahar. 2 Some historians have opined that Banasura and clan were assyrian 3. Yet others have concluded that Kapila Maharshi was somehwre in the vicinity of Colorado mountains when the sons of Sagara found him and suffered his curse. So even from your pov, your answer is inadequate. Oh and all dweepas have their specific names etc. to be used in kalpokta puja sankalap which is from yajurveda/purana.

Comment: @moonstar2001 - To be fair, those are speculations with no evidence/support form scriptures :). Colorado and sons of Sagara is just too much hahaha :). But if you can provide scriptural evidence to support Colorado, i will be happy to look at he evidence :)

Comment: @NilotpalSinha - To say that "the geography of events in all Hindu scriptures are confined only to the Indian sub-continent" is also subject speculation since so many scriptures/libraries have been destroyed or burned over the centuries, that we can never say for sure wether no references was in existence in "all Hindu scriptures". 

Also, you cannot deny the resemblance of Indonesian Hindu temples and the South American temple style. Try searching for "hanuman Copan". The resemble with Hanuman from the Ramayana is so striking that you cannot deny a possibility at the least.

Comment: @GabeHiemstra - Well in case things have been destroyed, then the best we can do is to go with whatever is mentioned in the available scriptures rather than saying that some events took place in Colorado, USA :)

Comment: @NilotpalSinha Is that really so hard to believe? I don't think you should make fun of such a remark. Again, the resemblance of Hanuman with the sculptures found in Copan is so striking, that it opens a lot of possibilities.

Comment: @GabeHiemstra  - I am believing in what is written in the scriptures and therefore I will make such a remark again regardless of who thinks what :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47316/discussion-on-answer-by-swami-factanand-are-hindu-scriptures-limited-to-india).

Comment: the question is specifically about the pyramids. you make no reference to these in your answer, nor do you give any references, only your opinion.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda: May be you didn't read it. Anyways here is an except from my answer ... " no known reference to the involvement of the people any other lands or anything in those lands"